# How can I translate CMYK to Pantone colors?

Tags: color-conversion, pantone

In particular, how do I translate CMYK `90C 85M 80Y 63K` to a Pantone color?

Comment: Do you have Photoshop?

Comment: That's a 318% ink coverage - which most print providers don't want or accept. Have those CMYK values been printed before? Best way to match a printed CMYK color is with a Printed Pantone matching guide.

Answer (score 4):

In Illustrator CC:

Fill in your desired shape with `90C 85M 80Y 63K` by selecting it in the `color picker` then press <kbd>ok</kbd>:

[image]

Select the shape with the filled color and go to `Edit -> Edit Colors -> Recolor Artwork...`:

[image]

Drop the color in the right panel titled `Color Groups`:

[image]

Click the drop down button and select `Color Books -> Pantone + Solid Coated`:

[image]

and it should be labeled instead of none:

[image]

Click the button <kbd>Ok</kbd> and save the item.  It should create a new color swatch folder with the color you chose at the very bottom:

[image]

Double click on the color and it will tell you `Pantone Black 6C`:

[image]